# Change the font color of weekend dates in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is it possible to change the font color of dates that fall on the weekends in jquery calendar? I try to use the class ui-datepicker-week-end but it only change the font color of Sun and Sat. What I want is to also change the color of days that falls on sun and sat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a bit more specificity in your selector, since `ui-datepicker-week-end` is on the `<td>`, but there's an `<a>` with `ui-state-default` inside, like this:

```
.ui-datepicker-week-end, .ui-datepicker-week-end a.ui-state-default {color:red;}
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Mk8Sj/).  If you're curious, the markup for day cell is like this:

```
<td class="ui-datepicker-week-end">
  <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">DAY NUMBER</a>
</td>
```